# Pandas: Crear columna de puntuación ponderando peso

Tags: python, pandas

He creado con python un dataframe en pandas con 2 columnas de puntuaciones. Me gustaría crear una nueva columna que obtenga una puntuación relacionada con esas 2 columnas pero que dé más valor a la segunda columna que a la primera. El principal problema llega porque las puntuaciones van desde -4 a 4 (siendo 4 la máxima y mejor puntuación) y no consigo que la puntuación final pondere bien cuando los números son negativos. Éste vendría a ser el df:

```
    Name       Puntuación A    Puntuación B
1   Player 1       3                4      
2   Player 2       1                4      
3   Player 3      -2               -1      
4   Player 4       2               -1
```

En ese ejemplo, me gustaría que el Player con mejor puntuación final sea el Player 2, seguido del 1, 3 y 4. Como veis, la idea es dar más peso a Puntuación B que a A pero sin minimizar del todo Puntuación A. Además, esta última columna de puntuación final tendría que estar escalada de 0 a 10, es decir, no tendría valores negativos. ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo poder generar esta nueva columna? Gracias!

Comment: Dices que en el ejemplo el resultado sería  Player 2, 1,3 y 4. ¿Cómo sacaste este orden? No  me queda claro puesto que le Player 1 a pesar que tiene mas puntuación A e igual puntuación B que Player 2. ¿No debería se primero Player 1? Quieres dar mas peso a Player 2 sobre Player 1 a pesar que éste tiene menor puntaje A?

Comment: Realmente no saqué ese orden... Me gustaría que, efectivamente, aunque el 1 tiene mejor puntuación que el 2, de alguna forma lo superase en la puntuación final. En caso de puntuación similar entre 2 en B, que prime en la puntuación final el que menos tenga en A. Eso sí, no sé si es posible, si te soy sincero, y por eso os pregunto a quienes sabéis más. Un saludo, Juan Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Logré hacer algo, pero no se que tan bien podría funcionar o que tan eficiente es, tal vez no sea la mejor solución pero es la que se me ocurrió a mi

> Un problema tiene diferentes soluciones

Para darle mas importancia a la columna `Puntuación B` se me ocurrió la idea de elevar al cuadrado su valor y para que `Puntuación A` también influya lo multiplique por `-1` asi si el valor de `Puntuación A` es bajo (por debajo de 0) se convertirá en mayor y si su valor es mayor, se convierte en menor, para determinar su valor solo sumamos ambos valores y dividimos entre 2 (ósea sacamos el promedio)

```py
#creamos una nueva columna con el valor
df["pon"] = (df["Puntuación A"]*-1+df["Puntuación B"]**2)/2
```

Para finalizar solo ordenamos los valores de forma descendente, según la columna `pon`

```py
df = df.sort_values("pon", ascending=False)
```

**resultado**

|  | Name | Puntuación A | Puntuación B | pon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Player 2 | 1 | 4 | 7.5 |
| 0 | Player 1 | 3 | 4 | 6.5 |
| 2 | Player 3 | -2 | -1 | 1.5 |
| 3 | Player 4 | 2 | -1 | -0.5 |

Comment: Gracias, Christian. Me ha gustado mucho esta posible solución. Voy a probarla a ver qué tal se dan los resultados. Un saludo

Comment: ok, avisame si tienes algun problema